# Dilworth's Theorem and Mirsky's Theorem for Infinite Posets?

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

I know that there is an infinite [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) that violates [Dilworth's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) and one that violates [Mirsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirsky%27s_theorem).  Unfortunately, I do not have access to the references for these counterexamples.  I have a few questions.

1. Can somebody please provide an explicit counterexample for each theorem?
2. I would like to know if there is an infinite partially ordered set that violates both theorems.  I am curious whether these theorems are true duals in the sense that a partially ordered set satisfies one of them if and only if it satisfies both.

> Let me call a partially ordered set $P$ *Dilworth* if the width of $P$ (i.e., the supremum of the cardinalities of antichains in $P$) is the same as the smallest cardinal number $c$ such that there exists a family $\mathcal{C}$ of chains in $P$ such that $P=\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ and $|\mathcal{C}|=c$.  A partially ordered set $P$ is *Mirsky* if the height of $P$ (i.e., the supremum of the cardinalities of chains in $P$) is the same as the smallest cardinal number $a$ such that there exists a family $\mathcal{A}$ of antichains in $P$ such that $P=\bigcup\mathcal{A}$ and $|\mathcal{A}|=a$.

For example, finite and countably infinite partially ordered sets are both Dilworth and Mirsky.  More generally, a partially ordered set of finite width is Dilworth, whereas a partially ordered set of finite height is Mirsky.  That is, the questions above can be rephrased as follows.

> 1. Please give me an example of a non-Dilworth partially ordered set and an example of a non-Mirsky partially ordered set.
> 2. Is there a partially ordered set which is simultaneously non-Dilworth and non-Mirsky?  Does it hold that a partially ordered set is Dilworth if and only if it is Mirsky?

Comment: A problem with your definitions is that the maximum cardinality of a chain (or antichain) does not necessarily exist, e.g., a poset may have a chain (or antichain) of cardinality $n$ for every finite $n$ but no infinite chain (or antichain). Would you like to rephrase your question in terms of suprems?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: However there is no need to change "minimum" to "infimum" because cardinal numbers are well-ordered (assuming the axiom of choice of course). I have edited your question to change this back and to improve the English grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1a.** Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable cardinal. Partially order the Cartesian product $P_\kappa=\kappa\times\kappa$ so that
$$\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\le\langle\alpha',\beta'\rangle\iff\alpha\le\alpha'\ \text{ and }\ \beta\le\beta'.$$
Then every antichain in $P_\kappa$ is finite, but $P_\kappa$ is not the union of $\lt\kappa$ chains. As $P_\kappa$ has cardinality $\kappa$ and height $\kappa,$ it is Mirsky but not Dilworth.

**1b.** Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable cardinal. Partially order the Cartesian product $Q_\kappa=\kappa\times\kappa$ so that
$$\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\lt\langle\alpha',\beta'\rangle\iff\alpha\lt\alpha'\ \text{ and } \beta\gt\beta'.$$
then every chain in $Q_\kappa$ is finite, but $Q_\kappa$ is not the union of $\lt\kappa$ antichains. As $Q_\kappa$ has cardinality $\kappa$ and width $\kappa,$ it is Dilworth but not Mirsky.

**2a.** If all chains *and* antichains in a partially ordered set $P$ are finite, then $P$ is finite by [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem). However, there is a poset $P$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ in which all chains and antichains are countable; of course such a $P$ is not the union of countably many chains or antichains, so it is neither Dilworth not Mirsky. The example is due to [Sierpiński](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wac%C5%82aw_Sierpi%C5%84ski): take the intersection of two linear orderings of $\mathbb R,$ the usual ordering and a well-ordering.

**2b.** I've already given natural examples of posets which are Mirsky but not Dilworth or Dilworth but not Mirsky. Still, it may be worth pointing out that, given a poset $P$ which is neither Dilworth nor Mirsky, we can trivially make it Mirsky-but-not-Dilworth by adjoining a large chain, or make it Dilworth-but-not-Mirsky by adjoining a large antichain.

Of course, any poset of finite height or width is both Dilworth and Mirsky.

Comment: Dear @bof, Why is every chain finite in 1b?

Comment: An infinite chain would contain either a strictly increasing infinite sequence $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)\lt(\alpha_2,\beta_2)\lt\cdots$ or else a strictly decreasing infinite sequence $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)\gt(\alpha_2,\beta_2)\gt\cdots$. Thus either $\beta_1\gt\beta_2\gt\cdots$ or else $\alpha_1\gt\alpha_2\gt\cdots$ would be a strictly decreasing infinite sequence of ordinals.